# Stop cursor in a UITextField or UITextView from blinking

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to stop the cursor in a `UITextView` or `UITextField` from blinking??

What I want is that the cursor should have a visible color (say blue or any other) but it should be non-blinking.

Comment: Did you look at the list of related questions? And please update your question with more information about what you are actually trying to do and explain why you don't want the cursor to blink.

Comment: You can try to set the colour of Tint to clear, its a hack but works :/

Comment: set `youtextField.tintColor = UIColor.Clear`. It will invisible the cursor and your textField still in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an invisible text field and make it the first responder. Once you're done, you can set the first responder back to the original text field and remove the invisible text field

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set the colour of Tint to clear, its a hack but works :/

```
textfield.tintColor = UIColor.Clear
```

Comment: Setting tintColor to clearColor will make the cursor invisible....i want to have a visible color for the cursor but stop its blinking